# Apache выдает ошибку при запуске: the requested operation has failed

Tags: apache2

Стоял денвер, решил установить apache последнюю версию. Денвер удалил, не помогло, менял порт с 80 на 8080 в httpd.conf  всеравно не помогло.

[image: Ошибка при запуске Apache]

Comment: начните с просмотра *error_log-а*.

Comment: Логов ошибок вообще нет, может потому что он так ниразу и не запустился

Comment: смотрели подсказки? http://serverfault.com/q/109650/292034

Comment: вот логи появились `Starting the 'Apache2.4' service
[Tue Jul 07 23:13:10.948606 2015] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 8440:tid 248] (OS 2)Не удается найти указанный файл.  : AH00378: Failed to start the 'Apache2.4' service`

Comment: возможно, не правильно указан путь к программе (или её имя).

Answer (score 4):

Проблема решилась удалением службы Apache2.4 и последующей переустановкой. Еще пришлось сделать некоторые изменения в http.conf а именно изменил имя папки на Apache2.4 во всех местах конфигурации. Ну и саму папку с сервером переименовал с Apache24 на Apache2.4